# Which set does this part belong to?

Tags: set-identification

Which set does this part belong to? Thanks very much!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are all the possible sets: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30382&in=S

To me, that piece looks dark blueish gray, which would suggest either set 4209 or set 8095.

Comment: It is hard to detect correct color. So there is also a chance this would be a Sand Blue colored part.

Comment: When I saw the picture I also though sand blue,